# Navigation bar hover

Tags: html, css

I'am stuck with this one thing in navigation bar. 
So I made ribbon navigation bar with hover when mouse over the element. I do have class ".active" then ribbon is little bit longer, but when i mouse over this active element ribbon decreases. I want to know how can make hover on everything except for that ".active" class, and also for drop-down content.

I think, there is a work with those Pseudo-elements like :not() but i'm not sure,i tried almost everything.

Thanks.

[Here is my HtTML+CSS code so far!](https://jsfiddle.net/foox2nq7/)

```
<nav role="top">

<ul>
<div class="ribbon">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li  class="active" ><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
       <li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a  href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a  href="#">Link 3</a>
  <li id="livechat" ><a href="#">About me</a></li>




</div>
</div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.active` is applied to the parent `li`, you need to use `:not()` on that to target `.active` or not, and then apply the CSS that changes when you hover a link

`nav[role="top"] li:not(.active) a:hover { ... }`

```css
nav[role="top"] ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  margin-top:0px;
}

nav[role="top"] li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding:0 8px;

}

nav[role="top"] a {
  display: block;
  color: #b3b3b2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 70px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
 
  
}

nav[role="top"] li:not(.active) a:hover  {
 
  height:1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #aecacc;
  color:#fff;
}





nav[role="top"] a:hover::after {
    margin-top:-18px;
 content: "";
  display: block;
  position: static;
  width: 0;
  height:20px;
  border-right: 35px solid #aecacc;
  border-left: 35px solid #aecacc;
  border-bottom: 12px solid rgba(224, 33, 33, 0); 
}



.active a {
 
  height:12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width:20px;
  
   background-color: #aecacc;

}

.active a:first-child {
 color:white;
}

.active::after {
   
    margin-top:0px;
 content: "";
  display: block;
  position: static;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border-right: 35px solid #aecacc;
  border-left: 35px solid #aecacc;
  border-bottom: 12px solid rgba(224, 33, 33, 0);
}



li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown-content {

    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;

}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(208, 208, 207, 0.2)

}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav role="top">

    <ul>
 <div class="ribbon">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li ><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
 <li  class="active" ><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
           <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a  href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a  href="#">Link 3</a>
   <li id="livechat" ><a href="#">About me</a></li>
  
   
  
   
    </div>
 </div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked!  And how about "dropdown-content" If i don't want ribbon to show up ?   I tried  nav[role="top"] a:not(.dropdown-content) li:not(.active) a:hover { ... }  but it wont work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the `:not()`. Add it to line 29 of your CSS

```
nav[role="top"] li:not(.active) a:hover  {
  height:1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #aecacc;
  color:#fff;
}
```